# How to stop and continue the process

Tags: linux, bash, unix, process

I used

```
ps -fT pid
```

to manage a bunch of process forked from the specified **pid**.

Now I want to modify some settings so I want to stop the processes whose pid is in `ps -fT pid`. After the modification I want them to continue running from the stopped state(not redo the process). For example if a process have 4 stages. If I stopped it when it was in second stage, I want to continue it from the second stage. How to do that?

Answer (score 0):

To suspend a process:

```
kill -STOP pid
```

To continue a suspended process:

```
kill -CONT pid
```